# How to match data in logstash one data input from API and second from csv file on server

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have tried all possible case but unable to match data between API and CSV file. my ultimate goal is read host key from REST API and matching with CSV file and print respective OS. Please suggest, Configuration as below -

```
    input{
  http{
      host => "*****"
      port => "****"
      type => "api_input"
     }
  file {
     path => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/Event.csv"
     start_position => "beginning"
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      skip_header => "true"
      columns => ["server", "os"]
      }
if [server] == [result][host] {
         mutate { add_field => { "OS_Name" => "%{[os]}" } }
           }

else{drop {}}
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

csv file data :-
server_1,Windows
server_2,Linux
server_3,Unix
server_4,Windows

API data :-
{"result":[{"host":"server_4","parameter":"22"}]}

Answer (score 1):

The [translate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html) filter can do a lookup of a field in a two column CSV file.

Comment: Hi @badger,  I have tried all possible ways but can't do a lookup of a field in a csv file.
can you please suggest the translate plugin logic. here is my existing approach. 
`filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      skip_header => "true"
      columns => ["server", "os"]
      ecs_compatibility => disabled
  }
translate {
        dictionary_path => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/Event.csv"
        source => "[result][host]"
        target => "[server]"
        fallback => "Matched"
       }`